# How to get the bigcommerce order that is updated using bigcommrece webhook in php?

Tags: php, bigcommerce, webhooks, orders

in demo.php

```
     $url='https://hooks-beta.bigcommerce.com';
      $fields = array(
     "producer"=>"store/bgf5e", 
     "scope"=>"store/order/*",
     "deliverymethod"=>"HTTP_POST",
     "destination"=>array(
     "url"=>"http://shopifywebhook.faculty.com/demo.php"
    ),
 );
```

I get the response
When i am updating the order in big commerce manually it give following result

string(160) "{"store_id":481868,"producer":"store/bgf5e","scope":"store/product/updated","data":{"type":"product","id":85},"hash":"2ca388118ff19587b5b1ed55fd58cdb74c3186aef4"}"

which is not related to    "scope"=>"store/order/*"
this scope i.e Order
What am doing wrong or that webhook is not working of bigcommerce?
I want the response to be order id and type "Order" but above you can
see that Product and Id =85

Thanks
Ranjeet Gholave

Comment: Anyone could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope is showing that you're subscribed to the wrong event: `store/product/updated`

Check your active webhooks using the CURL call below and confirm that you have the correct destination for the `/order/updated` scope- I found it was better to start with specific action scopes instead of wildcards.

```
curl -XGET -H 
  'X-Auth-Client: [BigCommerceAppClientId]' -H 
  'X-Auth-Token: [BigCommerceAppSecret]' 
https://hooks-beta.bigcommerce.com/producer/store/[myStoreKey]
```